# How to find the EXASOL server version with SQL

Tags: sql, exasol

I'm looking for a SQL query to provide me with the Exasol server version, similar to this in Oracle:

```sql
-- Oracle
select * from v$version;

-- PostgreSQL:
select version();
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also an option:

```
select *
from "$ODBCJDBC".DB_METADATA
where name in (
      'databaseIncrementVersion'
    , 'databaseMajorVersion'
    , 'databaseMinorVersion'
    , 'databaseProductVersion'
    , 'databaseName'
    , 'databaseProductName'
    , 'revisionNumber');
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```sql
select param_value from exa_metadata where param_name = 'databaseProductVersion';
```